# Problem: conservative and not conservative $F=\left( y+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}, x-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I don't know how I can solve this problem:

Consider

$$F=\left( y+\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}, x-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right).$$

Proving that $F$ is not conservative in $\mathbb{R}^2-(0,0)$ but is conservative in the domain

$$\Omega=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y>x^2\}$$

---

To prove that $F$ is conservative I calculated its rotational, but $\operatorname{rot}(F)=0$ so I did not prove nothing because if $\operatorname{rot}(F)=0$ then $F$ could be conservative or not conservative. So? what is what I have to do?. To prove that $F$ is conservative in that domain... I don't know... help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $F$ is not conservative on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$, compute the curve integral of $F$ along the unit circle. It will turn out to be non-zero, which shows $F$ can't be conservative.

For b), the domain $\Omega$ is simply connected, so the fact that $\operatorname{rot}(F) = 0$ on $\Omega$ is enough to guarantee that $F$ is convervative here. (You can also compute a potential function if you'd like.)

Comment: Ok, when I solve $\int_{0}^{2\pi} <F(\delta(t))|\delta'(t)>$ when $\delta(t)=(cos(\theta),sin(\theta))$ to $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ the result is $-2\pi$ and if it is so and the $rot(F)=0$... I don't apply the green's theorem? so $\int_{0}^{2\pi} <F(\delta(t))|\delta'(t)>\not=\int_{S}rot(F)$ to $S: unit\ circle$????